# Deleting empty space in Lex

Tags: c, ubuntu, flex-lexer, lex

Currenty I am trying to remove an empty string in a file with lex and c. My code is like following;

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
%}
keyword hava|su
ques "?"|"!"
%%
{keyword} {

yytext[0]=toupper(yytext[0]);
printf("%s",yytext);
}
{ques} {
if(yytext[-1]==' '){
ECHO;yytext++;
 }
 printf("%s", yytext);
 } 
  %%
 int main()
{
//yyin=fopen("test.txt","r");
yylex();
return 0;
}
int yywrap()
{
return 1;
}
```

I can see the empty space near a question mark, which, my aim is to delete it at once. But I fail doing it; I don't know how to do it. I tried a copy array and copying the new strings there but I get error since I am reading from a file.

Another task is to make the character after "ques" punctuations; also there, I can't reach to +1 characters.

For reaching to before and after characters, I use yytext[-1] and yytext[1] codes, -1 works to detect empty space but +1 fails to find the after character from the punctuations. What can be the problem?

My file is like following;

> hava gibi, su gibi, güneş gibi, toprak gibi vazgeçilmezdi. Onunla yatılıp onunla kalkılıyordu ve yaratıcı gücünün sonsuzluğuna, edebiyatın insanı insan yapma büyüsüne İnanılıyordu. Toplumun yozlaşmaya ve her şeyin parayla ölçüldüğü, bilgi ve kültüre duyulan saygının, kredi kartlarına, görselliğe yönelmeye başladığı yıllarda, edebiyat "Bir işlevi yok." ? düşüncesiyle gazetelerden kovuldu. Edebiyat kovulunca da gazeteler çirkinleşti, gazetelerle birlikte dil de espri de düşünce de sığlaşıp yüceliğini yitirdi ?Bense ona öylece bakıyordum?

Comment: The line `if(yytext[-1]==' ')` is extremely dubious.  There's no guarantee what's in that position.  It is undefined behaviour.  Maybe you should be searching for zero or more spaces followed by `?` or `!`, and only print the last character in `yytext`.

Comment: how can I detect 0 or more spaces in between "?" and something else?
edit: that isn't my question I have an idea. How can I omit white spaces? How can I only print "?" or "!"?

Comment: Define `space " "` or something similar (`space [ \t]` is tempting), then create a pattern `{space}*[?!]` to match zero or more spaces followed by a question mark or exclamation mark.  Then use `yytext[yylen-1]` to identify the last character, which will be either `?` or `!`.  (Check on the spelling of `yylen`; in case of doubt, use `strlen(yytext)`, but it shouldn't be necessary.)

Comment: Perhaps I should state that the pattern I showed (`{space}*{?!]`) would be used in the definition of `ques` or in place of `{ques}`.  The action would need fixing too

Comment: I changed it like following; 

%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
%}
keyword hava|su
//ques "?"|"!"
space*[?!] 
%%
{keyword} {
yytext[0]=toupper(yytext[0]);
printf("%s",yytext);
}

{space} { 
char lastchar = yytext[strlen(yytext)-1];
printf("%c", lastchar);
}

Getting unrecognized rule error. I am terribly sorry I am so new to this lex thing, but it is driving me crazy that I can't find the cause of such small error..

Comment: Please add the code to the question so you can format it and I can read it.  I'm not really willing to try reading what's in your comment.  (Note _add_; do not destroy the original code; add the new code too.)

Comment: wait not necessary. code works but not in the correct way. I am editing the last code which doesn't work the way we want it to be.

Comment: last version is in the question can you have a look at it?

Comment: I did say "please _add_ the code to the question".  I rolled back your edit because it changed the question and invalidated the commentary.  On the whole, it is best not to invalidate what has gone before.  It is very important when the assistance is in the form of answers; it is somewhat less important when the help is only in comments as here.

Comment: I didn't know that, I thought you said change the "original" code. Please omit my mistake and I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: can you check my other problem? I can't reach to the letters after question marks I declared within the scope to make them uppercase. I am using yytext[1] and they obviously don't work...

I tried the following; uppernext [?!][a-z]* {uppernext} {printf("%xc", toupper(yytext[1]));}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my version of your code that seems to work.  Note that I identify keywords that are mapped by surrounding them with `{` and `}`, and I identify mapped question marks and exclamation marks by surrounding them with `[` and `]`.  This helps reassure me that it is doing what I expect.  I wouldn't keep those in production code except as a debug assistant.

#### `tk11.l`

```
%{
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
%}

%option noinput
%option nounput

keyword hava|su
ques [ \t]*[?!]
%%

{keyword}   { yytext[0] = toupper(yytext[0]); printf("{%s}", yytext); }
{ques}      { printf("[%s]", &yytext[yyleng-1]); } 
.           { ECHO; }

%%

int main(void)
{
    yylex();
    return 0;
}

int yywrap(void)
{
    return 1;
}
```

#### `data`

This is a single line of 601 characters from Turkish (according to http://translate.google.com/) copied from the question:

```
hava gibi, su gibi, güneş gibi, toprak gibi vazgeçilmezdi. Onunla yatılıp onunla kalkılıyordu ve yaratıcı gücünün sonsuzluğuna, edebiyatın insanı insan yapma büyüsüne İnanılıyordu. Toplumun yozlaşmaya ve her şeyin parayla ölçüldüğü, bilgi ve kültüre duyulan saygının, kredi kartlarına, görselliğe yönelmeye başladığı yıllarda, edebiyat "Bir işlevi yok." ? düşüncesiyle gazetelerden kovuldu. Edebiyat kovulunca da gazeteler çirkinleşti, gazetelerle birlikte dil de espri de düşünce de sığlaşıp yüceliğini yitirdi ?Bense ona öylece bakıyordum?
```

It would be better if it was spread over multiple lines, but…

#### Output:

```
$ ./tk11 < data
{Hava} gibi, {Su} gibi, güneş gibi, toprak gibi vazgeçilmezdi. Onunla yatılıp onunla kalkılıyordu ve yaratıcı gücünün son{Su}zluğuna, edebiyatın insanı insan yapma büyüsüne İnanılıyordu. Toplumun yozlaşmaya ve her şeyin parayla ölçüldüğü, bilgi ve kültüre duyulan saygının, kredi kartlarına, görselliğe yönelmeye başladığı yıllarda, edebiyat "Bir işlevi yok."[?] düşüncesiyle gazetelerden kovuldu. Edebiyat kovulunca da gazeteler çirkinleşti, gazetelerle birlikte dil de espri de düşünce de sığlaşıp yüceliğini yitirdi[?]Bense ona öylece bakıyordum[?]
$
```

As you can see, `hava` and `su` have been captured and capitalized, and there are no spaces before any of the question marks any more.

Note that `sonsuzluğuna` was transliterated to `son[Su]zluğuna`; handling whole words as keywords requires more rules, handling the non-Latin alphabetic characters from the Turkish portion of the code set carefully.